# I'm stuck trying to clone a git repository which requires cmake files and dependancies

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to download and use this repo:(https://github.com/rstebbing/subdivision-regression)

I have downloaded this repo, it's dependencies and their dependencies. Once downloaded, I've changed the CMakeList files (as instructed) with the new locations of the packages but when I try and 'sudo make install' it can't find the packages and won't install.

I am on a linux machine. 
I downloaded these dependencies: ceres, common, gflags, rapidjson and believed they are install correctly.
When installing the **subdivision** I follow the git instructions and change the paths and ran *cmake* fine. When I use 'sudo make install' i get the error:

```
In file included from subdivision/doosabin/doosabin_pyx.h:12:0,
                 from subdivision/doosabin/doosabin_.cpp:615:
cpp/doosabin/include/doosabin.h:20:10: fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory
 #include "Eigen/Dense"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Even though I have specified the path to this file in the cpp/doosabin/CMakeLists and site.cfg:

site.cfg:

```
[Include]
EIGEN_INCLUDE ="/home/hert5584/RStebbing/eigen-git-mirror/"
COMMON_CPP_INCLUDE ="/home/hert5584/RStebbing/common/cpp/"ccd
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.0)

PROJECT(DOO-SABIN)

SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
SET ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11" )

MACRO(EXPECT_FILES VARIABLE)
  FOREACH(EXPECTED_FILE ${ARGN})
    IF (NOT EXISTS ${${VARIABLE}}/${EXPECTED_FILE})
      MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR
        "Caller defined ${VARIABLE}: ${${VARIABLE}} does not contain "
        "${EXPECTED_FILE}.")
    ENDIF (NOT EXISTS ${${VARIABLE}}/${EXPECTED_FILE})
  ENDFOREACH()
ENDMACRO(EXPECT_FILES)

SET(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR "/home/hert5584/RStebbing/eigen-git-mirror/")
EXPECT_FILES(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR Eigen/Dense)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

I also tested this without changing **subdivision** CMake files and only changing **subdivions-regression** and got a similar error about not finding functions.

Any help on how to install this properly, or any ideas about what I am doing wrong would be amazing!

Thank you

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Comment: The code is in both C++ and python so I thought it might be helpful - I have removed it now

Comment: Did you remember to run `cmake` after changing the CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: Yes, ran cmake which ran fine! Which assured me the file paths were correct (incorrect paths wouldn't run)

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in setting up CMake. I was changing the paths manually inside the CMakeList files whereas it should be done with cmake:

```
cmake -DCOMMON_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/RStebbing/common/cpp -DEIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/RStebbing/eigen-git-mirror ../subdivision/cpp/doosabin/
```

Now working